# Add a counter to a Power Point Presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint, counter

I would like to add a counter to a power point presentation. Someone mentioned to me that this might be doable in VBA. Do you know if this could be done in VBA and how?

Basically here is what I would like to do:
display a counter representing for example the number of cars rented since the beginning of my presentation. So for example, at the start the counter is at 0 and every minute is incremented of 2000 (this is just an example). We can see the counter on every slide, so at the end of my talk people can see (and I'll tell them) that since the beginning of the talk X(large number) cars have been rented.

I tried to find something on the internet but without success... I hope someone will be able to help me?

Comment: I am not sure whether this is better suited to superuser

Comment: Not sure whether it belongs on [su] but it's not suited for [so] (at least not in its current state), see [faq].

Comment: ok, my bad, I thought this was a practical question that could be asked.

Comment: @user1314776: Surely this is an interesting question, however, stackoverflow is more for specific programming problems.

Comment: As a side note - your question seems to indicate that you may want to get the number of cars rented from some external source, but then you mention incrementing it with a timer as an example, these are fundamentally different actions.

Comment: You may want to look into Visual Basic (VBA) (and possibly rephrase + retag the question appropriately, which would make it more appropriate for [so]).

Comment: the number of cars rented by minute a known value. This would just be the value used to increment the counter every minute. I don't need to get it from an external source. I just basically want to increment the counter with a given value every minutes.

Comment: @Dukeling: thanks for the advice, I changed the tags and tried to rephrase is a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I give you some ideas. Possibly they will be helpful even I do not provide any code.

1. Generally you need to have something like 'timer' in your presentation which would start with your presentation and count the time used. Unfortunately there is nothing like this in PowerPoint. You could possibly use some external solution like C# COM add-in but it's rather very complicated.
2. You could use PP application events but value of the car will not change every minute but every new slide you enter or any other event fires (like moving reverse, etc). It's a bit complicated but within our (StackOverflow users) knowledge.

You could possible search or ask under that [link](http://www.pptfaq.com) where I used to find lot's of interesting ideas.

**I promised** to provide solution therefore I'd like to do it even the question is closed. Therefore I do it by re-edition of that answer which I hope is allowed.

1. We have to be sure that there is a 'text box' where 'count value' would be placed on each slide. Add the following code into Module1 and run it.

   ```
   Sub Add_CarValue_Text()

   Dim SLD As Slide, SHP As Shape, shCarValue As Shape
   Dim boCarValue As Boolean

   For Each SLD In ActivePresentation.Slides
       For Each SHP In SLD.Shapes
           If SHP.Name = "CarValue" Then
               boCarValue = True
               Exit For
           End If
       Next

       If Not boCarValue Then
           Set shCarValue = SLD.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 0, 0, 150, 50)
           With shCarValue
               .Name = "CarValue"
               .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Cars counter: "
           End With

       End If
       boCarValue = False
   Next
   End Sub
   ```
2. Add new Class Module and place below code there. Change if necessary.

   ```
   Public WithEvents PPApp As Application

   Private TimerStart As Long
   Private Const increasePerMinute = 1000

   Private Sub PPApp_SlideShowBegin(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
       TimerStart = Int(Timer)
   End Sub

   Private Sub PPApp_SlideShowNextSlide(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
       If Not Wn.View.Slide.Shapes("CarValue") Is Nothing Then
           Dim Lap As Integer
           Lap = (Int(Timer) - TimerStart) / 10 'change for 60 to change from 10sec to 1 min
           Wn.View.Slide.Shapes("CarValue").TextFrame.TextRange = "Cars volume: " & Lap * increasePerMinute
       End If
   End Sub
   ```
3. Add the following code to Module2 and run the procedure.

   ```
   Public tmpPPApp As New AppClass
   Sub StartUp()
       Set tmpPPApp.PPApp = PowerPoint.Application
   End Sub
   ```
4. Start your presentation.

Important! If you change anything in code please run step 3 again. Moreover, just in case, you need to run procedure 3 always before you lunch the presentation.

Comment: ok, I'll study these different options and have a look at the link you gave. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the second solution would be enough, I mean 'value of the car' changes only when moving from slide to slide, I could try to provide code for you.

Comment: If it is possible, that could be a good alternative because using a timer seems quite complicated. Thanks.